# How to get Dnn version from c#

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

As **DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.DataBaseVersion** getting obsolete, how to get "Dnn Database Version" using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debug output of my theme/skin files I usually just do this as a 1 liner. Not sure if its the best, modern way, but currently not deprecated.

```
<p>DNN <%= DotNetNuke.Application.DotNetNukeContext.Current.Application.Version.ToString(3) %></p>
```

[image]